# PowerShell create array from ForEach and pipe into email body

Tags: arrays, email, powershell, csv, foreach

I am looping through a list of computers and checking disc space.  I want to format this information into an array that I can add as the email body.  I want the entire output into one email, I know how to send an individual email of each one.

Here is the code:

```
$ComputerList = IMPORT-CSV listofcomputers.txt
$tableFragment = ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerList){
$Name = $Computer.Name
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Name -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace
$b = ($disk.Size / 1073741824)
$a = ($disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824)
$a = "{0:N1}" -f $a
$b = "{0:N1}" -f $b
if($disk.FreeSpace -lt 10737418240){Write-Host Disk space on $Name is LOW.  Only $a GB remaining. -foregroundcolor "magenta"}
else{Write-Host Free disc space on $Name is $a GB, out of $b GB.}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this bit:

```
if($disk.FreeSpace -lt 10737418240){Write-Host Disk space on $Name is LOW.  Only $a GB remaining. -foregroundcolor "magenta"}
else{Write-Host Free disc space on $Name is $a GB, out of $b GB.}
```

to this:

```
if($disk.FreeSpace -lt 10737418240){ $body += "Disk space on $Name is LOW.  Only $a GB remaining.`r`n"}
else{ $body += "Free disc space on $Name is $a GB, out of $b GB.`r`n"}
```

You don't need an array of strings since the Send-MailMessage command's Body parameter expects a string.

If you want some header info, then at the top of your script declare $body:

```
$body = "Some header info.`r`n"
```

Comment: This works, but the `r`n do not seem to have any effect.  The email body is one long continuous string.  Do I have to format via HTML to get the line breaks? @Keith Hill

Comment: Hmm, I just did a test using Send-MailMessage using `"{backtick}r{backtick}n"` and it came through on different lines.  You shouldn't have to format as HTML.

Comment: I was using -BodyAsHTML.  When I removed that it worked great.  Thanks!